# How to create an post entry in blogspot using php?

Tags: php, blogger, blogspot

I want to post entries in my blogspot blog using php. But i just cant do it. I read the googlr blogger documentation but i just cant understant.
Can someone please tell me in simple words how to create an entry in blogspot?

Comment: Please elaborate on "I just can't do it".  What have you tried?  What was your error?  What specifically don't you understand?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [Blogger API](http://code.google.com/apis/blogger/).

Quoted from the targeted URL:

> The Blogger Data API allows client applications to view and update Blogger content in the form of Google Data API feeds. Your client application can use the Data API to create new blog posts, edit or delete existing posts, and query for posts that match particular criteria.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 - Generate your access token here - https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/

Step 2 - Make a Post request using Step 3 at Oauth 2 playground at the to check the request headers and body and make sure that your sending the Post request in the same manner.

Step 3 - Now replicate the same Http Post request from your code ( having same headers and body parameters )

** there is no way to preauthorize someone for Blogger so you have no way to do Step 1 through your Code.

** Moreover the access token expires after sometime( may be an hour ). So you will have to refresh / regenerate it periodically and then use a new one in your code.